# How to add entry to LDIF file using Spring Boot embedded ldap server

Tags: java, spring-boot, ldap, spring-ldap, ldif

I have built a spring boot REST app with LDAP authentication using unboundid as embedded ldap server. Authentication is based on simple LDIF file, and now I need the ability to add new entries to this file, so I could to authenticate with ones later. How can I save new entry directly to the LDIF?

I have tried to do that using `LdapTemplate`, but it works only for one session of application(as I understood, `LdapTemplate` adds new entry to some "internal, one-session-living" LDAP) and when application stops, LDIF file remains unchanged.

Here is my **application.properties** file

```
#LDAP config
spring.ldap.embedded.base-dn=dc=time-tracking-service,dc=com
spring.ldap.embedded.credential.username=uid=admin
spring.ldap.embedded.credential.password=pass1
spring.ldap.embedded.ldif=classpath:users.ldif
spring.ldap.embedded.validation.enabled=false
spring.ldap.embedded.port=8389
ldap.url=ldap://localhost:8389/
```

This is my **entry class**

```java
@Entry(
    objectClasses = {"inetOrgPerson", "organizationalPerson", "person", "top"}
)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public final class LdapPerson{

    @Id
    private Name dn;

    @DnAttribute(value = "uid", index = 1)
    private String uid;

    @DnAttribute(value = "ou", index = 0)
    @Transient
    private String group;

    @Attribute(name = "cn")
    private String fullName;

    @Attribute(name = "sn")
    private String lastName;

    @Attribute(name = "userPassword")
    private String password;

    public LdapPerson(String uid, String fullName, String lastName, String group, String password) {
        this.dn = LdapNameBuilder.newInstance("uid=" + uid + ",ou=" + group).build();
        this.uid = uid;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.group = group;
        this.password = password;
    }
```

And my **LdapConfig**

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableLdapRepositories
public class LdapConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LdapContextSource contextSource() {
        LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
        contextSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("ldap.url"));
        contextSource.setBase(env.getRequiredProperty("spring.ldap.embedded.base-dn"));
        contextSource.setUserDn(env.getRequiredProperty("spring.ldap.embedded.credential.username"));
        contextSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("spring.ldap.embedded.credential.password"));
        contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        return contextSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate() {
        return new LdapTemplate(contextSource());
    }
}
```

I add entry simply using

```java
ldapTemplate.create(ldapPerson);
```

I expected that using `LdapTemplate` I will be able to add new entry to the LDIF file, but it doesn't work, so I need help with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

> as I understood, LdapTemplate adds new entry to some "internal, one-session-living" LDAP

A bit late but you are correct, Spring's embedded LDAP doesn't change the contents of LDIF files upon save (and no LDAP implementation pretty much)

`ldapTemplate.create(ldapPerson);` just creates a new record in the in-memory LDAP instance you initialized above. When you terminate the application, everything is lost.

If you want to persist data you have to integrate with one [LDAP implementations](https://ldap.com/directory-servers/). Moreover `LdapTemplate` is configurable on Spring Boot through [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ldap.LdapAutoConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/ldap/LdapAutoConfiguration.html)